# Unity 3D [C#] - How to properly reset a scene

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem when I try to reset a scene. It doesn't seem to run, I have a script (of all scripts that have Awake and Start methods on that scene) that on the Awake method starts a coroutine, but when reseting the scene it doesn't even run it. I've read that it may be a problem of using the DontDestroyOnLoad method, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem since that script on the start takes a lot of references of objects that are only on the scene that I want to restart. I don't use any static variables on any script.

I made an unitary test trying to restart a scene with just one object and one script attached, on its Start method it also starts a coroutine but even in that test it doesn't even run the coroutine.

Here's the script of the unitary test:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadingSceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
    //Scene scene;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        useStartCoroutine();
    }

    void useStartCoroutine()
    {
        StartCoroutine(loadScene());
    }

    IEnumerator loadScene()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("gameplayScene 1");
        //SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("gameplayScene 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name); instead of the name.

Comment: that would be a solution for the case on which I would try to reset the scene from the active scene. But what happens if I want so replay the scene from another scene. Should I store the scene in a variable then?

Comment: There could be many methods to achieve this. See: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133872/how-to-store-variables-in-between-scenes-unity/133880#133880

Comment: Are you sure that you have added scene in Build section? and i prefer you using indexes of scenes instead of names, just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, the scene is added on build settings, when I load the scene for the first time it runs normal. The second time I try to load it its when it doesn't run...

Comment: So, all variables that I declare on the start of the scene need to access the persistent object you propose?

Comment: Im flagging this question to be closed. I copied your code into an empty project, ensured the names matched up, and sure enough - it worked *perfectly*. To be on topic, programming related questions must provide "a minimal ***verifiable*** example of the problem". Given your script works, you have *not* provided a verifiable example.

Comment: My guess is you havn't actually added the scenes to build; or alternativley, your getting the names wrong. Perhaps you could provide a screenshot of your build settings to clarify any confusion?

Comment: [Here is a screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb2FR.gif) of your script working correctly. Origin level contains a simple idling alien, the second level simply contains a giant red cube.

Comment: the problem goes once I replay the scene from other scene

Comment: @Gnemlock , he mean to delete everything in the scene , but leave one object with script attached , and script attached to the object must be only one . upvoting this post .

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter if you're calling a scene from one scene and trying to call another scene from that scene, you won't be able to. Unity unloads all scenes in the editor. Make a build and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

> ...the Awake method starts a coroutine, but when reseting the scene it doesn't even run it.

The [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) method is only called when a script is first loaded. Because your script has `DontDestroyOnLoad` (which you don't need to put in `Start` because you already have it in `Awake`), it will be carried over to any new scene that you load, and it **will not be loaded again,** so `Awake` will not be called again.

What you want is a method that subscribes to the `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` event:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnLevelLoaded;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnLevelLoaded;
}

private void OnLevelLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
{
    Debug.Log(string.Format("The level '{0}' was loaded.", scene.name));
}
```

This code will be called between the `Awake` and the `Start` methods when loading a scene.

A bit unrelated, but it's important to note that, because your original code has `DontDestroyOnLoad`, if you switch from a scene that has your `LoadingSceneController` object within it to a different scene, and then switch back to that scene, it will create a second instance of your `LoadingSceneController` object. You can fix this by spawning your `LoadingSceneController` object through code only once (if it doesn't already exist), or adding some code at the beginning of your script's `Awake` that will destroy its `gameObject` if another object with that script already exists.