# How do I keep Text[] values alive and reuse in the script

Tags: unity, data

I'm building a bowling game in which I am trying to save the number of pins fallen on every turn to a UI text box, taken as an array (`public Text[] Count`). I'm able to get the first score in the text box, but unable to save it while switching to other scenes.

There are two scenes; one has the ball, pins and alley, and the other scene has the score card, which is displayed in additive mode. The UI text is a child of the canvas. I've used `DontDestroyOnLoad` for the canvas, but it doesn't work at all.
I'm actually trying to reuse these values to display the score in the series.

Below is the code

```
public GameObject rootCanvas;
    public Text[] Count;
    public static int counter=0;
    public static int i;
    public static int co = 0;


    MovingBall ball = new MovingBall();

    public void Start()
    {
        ball.countText = GameObject.FindWithTag("Counttext").GetComponent<Text>();


        for (i=co;i<=29;i++)
        {
            if (counter < 1)
                {
                    Count[i].text = ball.countText.text;
                }
                else if (counter == 1)
                {
                    Count[i].text = ball.countText.text;
                    Count[i+1].text = (Convert.ToInt16(Count[i-1].text) + Convert.ToInt16(Count[i].text)).ToString();
                }

            counter++;

            co++;

            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject.transform);

            return;

        }

    }



    void Awake()
    {

        rootCanvas = GetComponent<GameObject>();

    }
```

Comment: By loading scene additive, `GameObject` never destroy. I think you are finding `Canvas` in script and you are getting first `Canvas` which may be the `Canvas` of second scene in which is not your desired `Canvas`. Can you show some of your code so we can analyze it?

Comment: @HamzaHasan there is only one canvas I've used which is independent. I've used Text[] Count which has all the textboxes as child. I've edited the code. Please refer to it.

Comment: Why are you doing this `rootCanvas = GetComponent<GameObject>();`?

Comment: Was just trying a way to reuse the values. Sort of like a fluke. Doesn't work though. So as we are Desi :D

Comment: Flagged this as a duplicate of: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/unity-5-what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes || Also take a look at this post: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133872/how-to-store-variables-in-between-scenes-unity/133880#133880

Answer (score -1):

You need to call [DontDestroyOnLoad()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

That will keep your "score" tracking object alive as Unity switches scenes.

Be aware that when you go to switch *back* you'll now have two of these objects! You'll need to either destroy the original (before switching scenes again) or detect and destroy the duplicate (by using a singleton structure).

Comment: The question author says they tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Philipp It would if you call it on the *Text objects too*

Comment: @Draco18s, Well I've tried on Text objects as well but it gives me error on it.

Comment: You don't call it on the text component, but on the text component's game object: `someText.gameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad()`

Comment: Its a Text array and not a game object.

Comment: ...soo loop over it and set all of them?

Comment: Count[i].gameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(); like this you are saying?
This generates error. 
DontDestroyOnLoad(Count[i].gameObject);
Tried this one as well but didn't work :(

Comment: What's the error?